# Dynamically assign different material to different points and line segments in THREE js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am building a graph using THREE.points and THREE.LineSegments:

```
points = new THREE.Points(pointsGeometry, pointMaterial);
lines = new THREE.LineSegments(lineGeometry, lineMaterial);
```

and I use:

```
raycaster.intersectObject(points)
[...]
intersected.geometry.colors[index] = color;
intersected.geometry.colorNeedUpdate = true;
```

to show the user which point is being hovered on.

What I'd like to do next is change the opacity of the other points and lines that are not connected to the point being hovered on. I can change the opacity of all the points and lines but not individually, i.e. there isn't a opacity array on the geometry or material attributes for the points.

What would be the best approach to accomplish this in THREE js? Also I cannot give a working code example because of work...

Thank you!

Comment: yes but there is color info i.e. `rgba`; use the `a` for opacity.

Comment: I've tried using rgba for the color attribute and it just ignored the alpha channel.

Comment: Set your materials to `transparent:true` to enable alpha changes from `opacity: x`

Comment: That works if I want all points to have the same opacity. What I need is when the user hovers on point A, it stays opaque and the other become transparent.